# Search a "title" and show "description" from XML in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have inputtext Search field if i Enter Title for ex(1-prop or 2-prop) in the field and press/Enter search then it should search the title and Title Codes for ex(t1...t4) or (a1....a4) from XML. and display in Dynamic Text field
How can i do that please help me!!....

```
<letter>
    <title>#</title>
    <mainTerm>
        <title>1-prop</title>
        <cell col="2">t1</cell>
        <cell col="3">t2</cell>
        <cell col="4">t3</cell>
        <cell col="5">t4</cell>
        <cell col="6">--</cell>
        <cell col="7">--</cell>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
        <title>2-prop</title>
        <cell col="2">a1</cell>
        <cell col="3">a2</cell>
        <cell col="4">a3</cell>
        <cell col="5">a4</cell>
        <cell col="6">--</cell>
        <cell col="7">--</cell>
    </mainTerm>
</letter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search a text (the title in your case) in your XML content using [E4X](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html) ( [ECMAScript for XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html) ) like this for example :

```
var xml:XML = 
    <letter>
        <title>#</title>
        <mainTerm>
            <title>1-prop</title>
            <cell col="2">t1</cell>
            <cell col="3">t2</cell>
            <cell col="4">t3</cell>
            <cell col="5">t4</cell>
            <cell col="6">--</cell>
            <cell col="7">--</cell>
        </mainTerm>
        <mainTerm>
            <title>2-prop</title>
            <cell col="2">a1</cell>
            <cell col="3">a2</cell>
            <cell col="4">a3</cell>
            <cell col="5">a4</cell>
            <cell col="6">--</cell>
            <cell col="7">--</cell>
        </mainTerm>
    </letter>;

var cells:XMLList = xml.mainTerm.(title == '2-prop').cell;

for each(var cell:XML in cells) {
    trace(cell);    // gives for example : "a1"
}
```

you can also use `for each` loops like this :

```
for each(var term:XML in xml.mainTerm){
    if(term.title == '2-prop'){
        for each(var cell:XML in term.cell){
            trace(cell);    // gives for example : a3 
        }
    }
}
```

For more about working with XML, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: thanks..but my Xml have 50 titles and there releated cell ..how can i modify(title=="") for 50 titles...

Comment: @Dev `title == '2-prop'` here is just an example, you'll get your title from a text field, so you can do  : `title == text_field.text` ... Is that what you meant ?

Comment: Thanks for Solution...... now my output : 2-prop: a1a2a3a4----................how can i add space between like(a1, a2, a3, --, --)

Comment: and also..one more...how can i do this:   just type "a1" in input panel and click search then output will: 2-prop: a1, a2, a3.....